# How to place designed walls of a tetrahedron?

Tags: mesh, objects

I designed four triangular walls (STL objects) and want to join them into a tetrahedron. I did it manually but it's not precise.

[image: My result]

Is there a way to replace the faces of the created tetrahedron or to join them in some other way?

Comment: maybe Tissue addon... to be tested on the meshes you have. Test it (Tissue is included with Blender), if that does not work, please share your blend file. https://blend-exchange.com/